# Is it fine to use one HttpClient instance for each host my application needs to talk to?

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I know that, when using the Microsoft dependency injection container, the best practice to handle HttpClient instances is using the [IHttpClientFactory interface](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/IHttpClientFactory.cs) provided by the [Microsoft.Extensions.Http nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/).

Unfortunately the classes implementing the [IHttpClientFactory interface](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/IHttpClientFactory.cs) are not public ([as you can verify here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/fc2a7eadfedd88f951eaecd45ecac6989b0f897f/src/HttpClientFactory/Http/src/DefaultHttpClientFactory.cs#L18)), so the only way to exploit this pattern is using the Microsoft dependency injection container (at least it's the only one that I know). Sometimes I need to maintain old applications using a different container, so I need to figure out a best practice even when the IHttpClientFactory approach cannot be used.

As explained in [this famous article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and [confirmed in the Microsoft docs too](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) the HttpClient class is designed to be instantiated once per application lifetime and reused across multiple HTTP calls. This can safely be done because the public methods used to issue HTTP calls [are documented to be thread safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), so a singleton instance can be safely used. In this case, it is important to follow the tips given [in this article](http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html) in order to avoid issues related with DNS changes.

So far so good.

Sometimes it is handy to use properties like [BaseAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.baseaddress?view=netframework-4.8) or [DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8), which are not thread safe (at least, they are not documented to be thread safe, so I assume they are not) to configure the HttpClient instance.

This opens a question: what happens if I have a singleton HttpClient instance and somewhere in my code I use the property [DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8) to set some common HTTP request headers useful to call one of the host my application needs to communicate with ? This is potentially dangerous, because different hosts could require different values for the same request header (think of authentication as an example of that). Furthermore, modifying [DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8) concurrently from two threads could potentially mess up the internal state of the HttpClient instance, because of the lack of thread safety guarantees.

For all these reasons, I think that the best approach to use HttpClient (when IServiceCollection is not available) is the following:

- create **one instace of HttpClient for each host the application
  needs to communicate with**. **Every call to one specific host will
  then use the same instance of HttpClient**. Concurrent calls to the
  same host are safe, because of the documented thread safety of
  methods used to perform calls.
- create **one service for each host the application needs to
  communicate with**. The HttpClient instance is injected inside this
  service and the service itself is used as a singleton in the
  application. This service is used to abstract away the access to the
  host it is coupled with. Classes like this are fully testable [as illustrated here](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/).
- the only point where instances of HttpClient are created and configured is the composition root of the application. The code in the composition root is single threaded, so it is safe to use properties like [DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8) to configure the HttpClient instances.

Do you see any problem in creating one instance of HttpClient per host to be called ?

I know that instantiating one HttpClient per request can lead to [socket exhaustion](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and must be avoided, but I guess that having one instance per host **is safe** with regard to this problem (because the same instance is used for all the requests to the same host and I do not expect that a single application needs to talk with a large number of different hosts).

Do you agree ? Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Side note: q does not say whether it is client or server side code... In case of server side code it would be better to remove DefaultRequestHeaders calls rather than considering this fix if headers ever may be user-specific (like auth you've mentioned).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have both client apps and server apps. Of course a possible approach is avoiding the DefaultRequestHeaders at all and properly configure the HttpRequestMessage on every single request performed. In this case using one singleton instance of HttpClient seems the best solution to me.

Comment: It’s not `HttpClient` that you should manage, but `HttpClientHandler`. It’s not hard to reimplement `IHttpClientFactory` either - just remember to use a time-limited pool of `HttpClientHandler` instances - IIRC it’s 2 minutes.

Comment: Side note 2: "thread safe" and "make any sense/produce reasonable results" are not necessary the same thing - setting sharing property *by itself* may be thread safe but there is absolutely no way for a class to guarantee that sequence of several unrelated calls (like setting `BaseAddress`, `DefaultRequestHeaders` and sending request) will result in outcome you want - while class may handle each operation safely there will be no way to know what values actually be used for the "send request" as other thread could have *safely* changed those value in mean time.

Comment: @Dai I've never checked the implementation of the IHttpClientFactory, as you said I know that it works by pooling the HttpClientHandlers and that each item in the pool has a limited lifetime. Reimplementing it could be an interesting exercise, but I'm not confident enough to go to production with a home made version of IHttpClientFactory. For core stuff like this, I prefer to use code provided by experts, like the guys who have designed IHttpClientFactory.

Comment: As for question itself - I believe small fixed number of HttpClient will not be a problem and essentially coding style - for me managing singleton and "instance per invocation" is generally easier than "reuse one of several instances based on some conditions" - so I'd try to just ensure singleton HttpClient is used safely...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Preface: As of mid-2023, Microsoft has updated their documentation re:
`HttpClient` and `IHttpClientFactory`; I recommend reading the following articles for background info on `IHttpClientFactory` and current usage guidelines (as-of .NET 7):

- [Guidelines for using HttpClient[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines)
- [Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests)
- [IHttpClientFactory with .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory)

---

> I know that, when using the Microsoft dependency injection container, the best practice to handle `HttpClient` instances is using the `IHttpClientFactory` interface provided by the [`Microsoft.Extensions.Http`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/) nuget package.

Correct.

> Unfortunately the classes implementing the IHttpClientFactory interface are not public (as you can verify here), so the only way to exploit this pattern is using the Microsoft dependency injection container (at least it's the only one that I know). Sometimes I need to maintain old applications using a different container, so I need to figure out a best practice even when the `IHttpClientFactory` approach cannot be used.

`Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` ("MEDI") should be thought of a (simplistic) abstraction over multiple DI systems - it just so happens to come with its own basic DI container. You **can** use MEDI as a front for Unity, SimpleInject, [Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection), Ninject, and others.

> As explained [in this famous article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and confirmed in the Microsoft docs too the `HttpClient` class is designed to be instantiated once per application lifetime and reused across multiple HTTP calls.

Not exactly:

- You don't want a **singleton** `HttpClient` used by all consumers of `HttpClient` in your application because different consumers might have different assumptions about (as you later point out) `DefaultRequestHeaders` and other `HttpClient` state. Some code may also assume that `HttpClient` is not using any `DelegatingHandler` instances either.
- You also don't want any instances of `HttpClient` (created using its own parameterless constructor) with an unlimited lifetime because of how its default internal `HttpClientHandler` handles (or rather, doesn't handle) DNS changes. Hence why the default `IHttpClientFactory` imposes a lifetime limit of 2 minutes for each `HttpClientHandler` instance.

> This opens a question: what happens if I have a singleton HttpClient instance and somewhere in my code I use the property DefaultRequestHeaders to set some common HTTP request headers useful to call one of the host my application needs to communicate with?

What happens? What happens is what you can expect: different consumers of the same `HttpClient` instance acting on wrong information - such as sending the wrong `Authorization` header to the wrong `BaseAddress`. This is why `HttpClient` instances should not be shared.

> This is potentially dangerous, because different hosts could require different values for the same request header (think of authentication as an example of that). Furthermore, modifying DefaultRequestHeaders concurrently from two threads could potentially mess up the internal state of the HttpClient instance, because of the lack of thread safety guarantees.

This isn't necessarily a "Thread safety" issue - you can have a single-threaded application that abuses a singleton `HttpClient` this way and still have the same issue. The real issue is that different objects (the consumers of `HttpClient`) are assuming that they are the **owner** of the `HttpClient` when they aren't.

Unfortunately C# and .NET do not have a built-in way to declare and assert ownership or object lifetimes (hence why `IDisposable` is a bit of a mess today) - so we need to resort to different alternatives.

> create one instace of HttpClient for each host the application needs to communicate with. Every call to one specific host will then use the same instance of HttpClient. Concurrent calls to the same host are safe, because of the documented thread safety of methods used to perform calls.

(By "host" I assume you mean HTTP "origin"). This is naive and won't work if you make different requests to the same service with different access-tokens (if the access-tokens are stored in `DefaultRequestHeaders`).

> create one service for each host the application needs to communicate with. The HttpClient instance is injected inside this service and the service itself is used as a singleton in the application. This service is used to abstract away the access to the host it is coupled with. Classes like this are fully testable as illustrated here.

Again, don't think of HTTP services in terms of "hosts" - otherwise this has the same problem as above.

> the only point where instances of HttpClient are created and configured is the composition root of the application. The code in the composition root is single threaded, so it is safe to use properties like DefaultRequestHeaders to configure the HttpClient instances.

I'm not sure how this helps either. Your consumers might be stateful.

Anyway, the real solution, imo, is to implement your own `IHttpClientFactory` (it can also be your own interface!). To simplify things, your consumers' constructors won't accept a `HttpClient` instance, but instead accept the `IHttpClientFactory` and call its `CreateClient` method in order to get their own **privately-owned and stateful** instance of `HttpClient` which then uses the pool of **shared and stateless** `HttpClientHandler` instances.

Using this approach:

- Each consumer gets its own private instance of `HttpClient` that they can alter as they like - no worries about objects modifying instances that they don't own.
- Each consumer's `HttpClient` instance **does not need to be disposed** - you can  safely disregard the fact they implement `IDisposable`.

  - Without pooled handlers, each `HttpClient` instance owns its own handler, which must be disposed.
  - But with pooled handlers, as with this approach, the pool manages handler lifetime and clean-up, not the `HttpClient` instances.
  - Your code **can** call `HttpClient.Dispose()` if it *really* wants to (or you just want to make FxCop shut-up) but it wont do anything: the underlying `HttpMessageHandler` (`PooledHttpClientHandler`) has a NOOP dispose method.
- Managing the lifetime of `HttpClient` is irrelevant because each `HttpClient` only owns its own mutable state like `DefaultRequestHeaders` and `BaseAddress` - so you can have transient, scoped, long-life'd or singleton `HttpClient` instances and it's okay because they all dip into the pool of `HttpClientHandler` instances only when they actually send a request.

Like so:

```cs
    /// <summary>This service should be registered as a singleton, or otherwise have an unbounded lifetime.</summary>
    public sealed class QuickAndDirtyHttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory // `IHttpClientFactory ` can be your own interface. You do NOT need to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Http`.
    {
        private readonly HttpClientHandlerPool pool = new HttpClientHandlerPool();

        public HttpClient CreateClient( String name )
        {
            PooledHttpClientHandler pooledHandler = new PooledHttpClientHandler( name, this.pool );
            return new HttpClient( pooledHandler );
        }

        // Alternative, which allows consumers to set up their own DelegatingHandler chains without needing to configure them during DI setup.
        public HttpClient CreateClient( String name, Func<HttpMessageHandler, DelegatingHandler> createHandlerChain )
        {
            PooledHttpClientHandler pooledHandler = new PooledHttpClientHandler( name, this.pool );
            DelegatingHandler chain = createHandlerChain( pooledHandler );
            return new HttpClient( chain );
        }
    }

    internal sealed class HttpClientHandlerPool
    {
        public HttpClientHandler BorrowHandler( String name )
        {
            // Implementing this is an exercise for the reader.
            // Alternatively, I'm available as a consultant for a very high hourly rate :D
        }

        public void ReleaseHandler( String name, HttpClientHandler handler )
        {
            // Implementing this is an exercise for the reader.
        }
    }

    internal sealed class PooledHttpClientHandler : HttpMessageHandler
    {
        private readonly String name;
        private readonly HttpClientHandlerPool pool;

        public PooledHttpClientHandler( String name, HttpClientHandlerPool pool )
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.pool = pool ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pool));
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync( HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken )
        {
            HttpClientHandler handler = this.pool.BorrowHandler( this.name );
            try
            {
                return await handler.SendAsync( request, cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.pool.ReleaseHandler( this.name, handler );
            }
        }

        // Don't override `Dispose(Bool)` - don't need to.
    }
```

Then each consumer can use it like so:

```cs
    public sealed class Turboencabulator : IEncabulator
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        public Turboencabulator( IHttpClientFactory hcf )
        {
            this.httpClient = hcf.CreateClient();
            this.httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Authorization", "my-secret-bearer-token" );
            this.httpClient.BaseAddress = "https://api1.example.com";
        }

        public async Task InverseReactiveCurrentAsync( UnilateralPhaseDetractor upd )
        {
            await this.httpClient.GetAsync( etc );
        }
    }

    public sealed class SecretelyDivertDataToTheNsaEncabulator : IEncabulator
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClientReal;
        private readonly HttpClient httpClientNsa;

        public SecretelyDivertDataToTheNsaEncabulator( IHttpClientFactory hcf )
        {
            this.httpClientReal = hcf.CreateClient();
            this.httpClientReal.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Authorization", "a-different-secret-bearer-token" );
            this.httpClientReal.BaseAddress = "https://api1.example.com";

            this.httpClientNsa = hcf.CreateClient();
            this.httpClientNsa.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add( "Authorization", "TODO: it's on a postit note on my desk viewable from outside the building" );
            this.httpClientNsa.BaseAddress = "https://totallylegit.nsa.gov";
        }

        public async Task InverseReactiveCurrentAsync( UnilateralPhaseDetractor upd )
        {
            await this.httpClientNsa.GetAsync( etc );
            await this.httpClientReal.GetAsync( etc );
        }
    }
```