# Correct usage of c# HttpClient and HttpClientFactory for Dns Round Robin Load Balancing

Tags: c#, load-balancing, dotnet-httpclient, consul

I have a question about the correct way to handle DNS Round Robin Balancing in c# with the HttpClient.

Say you have an API (API 1) which on request potentially calls another API (API 2). So you could have multiple concurrent requests into API 1 calling API 2 multiple times. What is the best way to enabled DNS round robin?

In our case we have APIs in a Kubernetes clusters with multiple replicas for both API 1 and 2. We use Consul Side Car Inject for Service Location (https://www.consul.io/docs/platform/k8s/connect.html)

When we use the HttpClientFactory to resolve the HttpClient like this.

```
private async Task<string> MakeSomeRequest(string endpoint)
{
    // IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory is injected in the constructor
    var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

    httpClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;

    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

We hit the problem that the DNS round robin loadbalencing is not used because the socket is kept open and the HttpClient connection is shared for all the requests. So API 1 gets the first connection to the first instance of API 2 and keeps hitting the same one across all the threads on API 1.

Currently we have ditched the use of the httpClientFactory in favor of ol faithful. Which works because it doesnt keep the socket open.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
    result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(endpoint, payload);
    return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I have considered multiple named registrations of the HttpClientFactory and then randomly selecting one but I'm curious to know if there is a better way?

Comment: Have you tried `httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close")` ?

Comment: @JohnWu does that just close the socket? I have not tried it.
I would prefer if it was possible to keep a socket per instance of API 2 open.

Comment: Seen teen question posted several minutes before yours - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58652432/is-it-fine-to-use-one-httpclient-instance-for-each-host-my-application-needs-to that gives all links you ever needed to setup HttpClient? In particular http://byterot.blogspot.com/2016/07/singleton-httpclient-dns.html

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That question/awsner does not seem cover the concept that I asked. Thought its detailed and a good read. I specifically want to know how people deal with keeping open and choosing a socket in away that achieves round robin dns load balancing.